# Wordpress Search Results Based on Current Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering how I would go about customizing search results based on which page the user is currently on in my Wordpress site.

I'm building a support/help center style website for a system that contains multiple versions, and I would like the search results to be based on which "version" the user is looking at.

Here's some more context, I have:

**system.com/version1**

**system.com/version2**

If a user uses a search form on a page in /version1, I would like the results to be only pages also in /version1. If a user uses a search form on a page in /version2, I would like the results to be from /version2

Is this possible, and if so what would be the easiest way to go about implementing it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `pre_get_posts` action hook. This will allow you to modify the `query` object depending on what page you are on. [Documentation here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

I haven't been able to test this yet, but you might start with something like this:

```
function my_children_query( $query ) {
    global $post; // not sure if this is needed

    // do nothing if we aren't on a search page
    if( !$query->is_search) {
        return;
    }

    // get only children of current page
    if( is_page( 'something1' ) || is_page( 'something2' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_parent', $post->ID );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_children_query' );
```